# How should I remove one string from the start of another given that I know the longer string matches case-insensitively?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, case-folding

Suppose I have a workflow that involves examining the start of a long string (`LS`, say) to see whether it begins with a shorter string `SS`. If it does, I chop off the matching part of `LS` and do something with the remaining part. Otherwise, I do something else. (The specific case that prompted this question was a parsing library.)

```
def do_thing(LS, SS):
    if (LS.startswith(SS)):
        action_on_match(LS[len(SS):])
    else:
        action_on_no_match()
```

This is straightforward. Now, though, suppose that I want to do the same thing but this time I want the strings to be matched case-insensitively. It is possible to test whether "`LS.startswith(SS)` but case-insensitively". But how should I determine how much of `LS` to "chop off" when I pass it in to `action_on_match()`? It isn't sufficient to just use `len(SS)` as it was before, because if I'm uppercasing or lowercasing or casefolding things, then the length of the matching prefix of `LS` might not be what I expect: changing the case of a string can change its length. It is important that the part of `LS` passed to `action_on_match()` be exactly what the program received as input (after the cutoff point, of course).

---

Answerers have suggested using `lower()` and preserving the use of `len(SS)`, but this will not work:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def action_on_match (s): return "Match: %s" % s
...
>>> def action_on_no_match (): return "No match"
...
>>> def do_thing (LS, SS):
...     if LS.lower().startswith(SS.lower()):
...         return action_on_match(LS[len(SS):])
...     else:
...         return action_on_no_match()
...
>>> do_thing('i\u0307asdf', '\u0130')
'Match: \u0307asdf'
>>>
```

Here we expect to see `'Match: asdf'`, but there is an extra character.

Comment: `changing the case of a string can change its length`: Can you elaborate more on that..?

Comment: @mu, U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S becomes "SS" when converted to uppercase. U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE becomes two characters (U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I and U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE) when converted to lowercase.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @JamieCockburn, question edited to clarify Python 3.

Comment: I'm not sure you assertion is correct: `>>> s1 = 'i\u0307'; s2 = '\u0130'` `>>> len(s1) == len(s1.lower())`: `True` `len(s1) == len(s1.lower())`: `True`

Comment: You are doing s1 twice and not doing s2 at all.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was copy/paste error. However, if you try `len(s2) == len(s2.lower())`, you still get `True`

Comment: Ah, okay, I get it now, it's not that the length *changes* as you state, but that different length strings compare okay if unicode combining characters are used.

Comment: `len(s2) == len(s2.lower())` is `False` for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
def do_thing(LS, SS):
    if LS.lower().startswith(SS.lower()):
        action_on_match(LS[len(SS):])
    else:
        action_on_no_match()
```

All I'm doing is lower-casing both `LS` and `SS` and then comparing them. This will be much slower than a regex solution for very long strings, as it has to convert the entire string to lowercase first.

A regex solution would look like this:

```
import re

def do_thing(LS, SS):
    if re.match("^%s" % SS, LS, re.I):
        action_on_match(LS[len(SS):])
    else:
        action_on_no_match()
```

**Performance**

For short strings (`len(LL)` == 8 characters) over 1000000 iterations:

- `lower()` method: 0.86s *(winner)*
- `re` method: 1.91s

For long strings (`len(LL)` == 600 characters) over 1000000 iterations:

- `lower()` method: 2.54s
- `re` method: 1.96s *(winner)*

**Unicode combining characters**

For unicode combining characters, the data needs to be [normalised](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) first.  This means converting any [precomposed character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) into its component parts.  You will find for example:

```
>>> '\u0130' == 'I\u0307'
False
>>> normalize("NFD", '\u0130') == normalize("NFD", 'I\u0307')
True
```

You will need to perform this normalisation process on your inputs:

```
SS = normalize("NFD", SS)
LS = normalize("NFD", LS)
```

Comment: Please see my edit to the question for why your modification to do_thing() will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.lower`, the length of `"FOO"` is going to be the same as `"foo".lower()`:

```
LS.lower().startswith(SS.lower())



def do_thing(ls, ss):
    if ls.startswith(ss):
        action_on_match(ls[len(ss):])
    else:
        action_on_no_match()
```